# Xamarin Forms Sending Image

Tags: c#, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to send an image to my server using a multipart data form, but whenever I attempt to send it I am timing out due to a lack of response. I am able to connect to the server when I try to post an HTTPContent object, but am having problems once I throw in MultiPartFormDataContent objects. I have tested the PHP code with an html form, so I know the problem lies in my Xamarin code

Xamarin Code:

```
MultipartFormDataContent Content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
HttpContent FileContent = new ByteArrayContent(Appointment.PicBytes);
Content.Add(FileContent, "AppointmentPicture", "AppointmentPicture");
HttpResponseMessage Response = await Client.PostAsync(Uri, Content);
string Details = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: how large is the image?  what is your timeout value set to?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
string convertedImage = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
HttpContent content = new StringContent(convertedImage, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```